# Rebol 3 What are the available border effects for r3gui?

Tags: rebol, rebol3

I know how to adjust the size of the border within r3gui:

```
view [
    b: box 800x400 red options [
        box-model: 'frame border-size: [4x2 2x4]
    ]
]
```

But how can I make an ibevel border/edge effect known from R2/View with r3gui?

Rebol2/View example:

```
view [
    box 800x400 red edge [size: 4x4 effect: 'ibevel color: gray]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'ibevel effect is not directly supported in Rebol3. But you should be able to achieve it using R3-GUI widget style customization using draw dialect:

```
stylize [
    my-box: box [
        facets: [
            border-colors: [
                65.65.65 191.191.191
            ]
        ]
        draw: [
            line-width 1 fixed
            pen border-colors/1
            fill-pen border-colors/1;
            polygon border-box/top-left border-box/top-right (as-pair border-box/top-right/x - border-size/2/1 border-box/top-right/y + border-size/1/2) (border-box/top-left + border-size/1)
            (as-pair border-box/bottom-left/x + border-size/1/1 border-box/bottom-left/y - border-size/2/2) border-box/bottom-left
            pen border-colors/2 ;
            fill-pen border-colors/2
            polygon border-box/bottom-right border-box/top-right 
            (as-pair border-box/top-right/x - border-size/2/1 border-box/top-right/y + border-size/1/2) (as-pair border-box/bottom-right/x - border-size/2/1 border-box/bottom-right/y - border-size/2/2)
            (as-pair border-box/bottom-left/x + border-size/1/1 border-box/bottom-left/y - border-size/2/2) border-box/bottom-left
        ]
    ]
]

view [
    my-box 300x300 red options [
        border-size: [4x2 2x4]
    ]
    my-box 300x300 red options [
        border-size: [4x8 12x24]
        border-colors: [0.0.255 0.255.0]
    ]
]
```